# Is it true that Selenium works only in headless mode in production? (Django)

Tags: python, django, selenium, django-views, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Django view function:

```
def bypass_link(request, pk=None):
    instance = fields.objects.get(pk=pk)
    link = instance.quote
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

    driver.get(link)
    driver.find_element_by_id("butAgree").click()
    return redirect(link)
```

template:

```
<td data-label="Quote">
    <a href="{% url 'bypass_link' i.id %}" target="_blank">{{ i.link }}</a>
</td>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url 

url(r'^bypass_link/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.bypass_link, name="bypass_link"),
```

This opens two links when I click on the hyperlink. When I remove the `return redirect(link)`, this shows the error on the page but the selenium window is working fine.

I just want to open the selenium window when clicking on the hyperlink.

Edits:

I changed the line to  `return redirect(index)`, this worked on local. But when I tried this on production, this shows an error. This error was solved if I run selenium in headless mode. But, I don't want to run in headless mode in production. Is it true that Selenium works only in headless mode in production?

Comment: The webdriver subprocess ("selenium window") runs on the server side, you can't open it on the client side (user's device).

Comment: Can you show how it works when you "run in headless mode"?

Comment: it redirects to the page, which means it is running in headless mode `options.headless = True `, without this line, it shows an error in production, that chrome failed. This is not an issue in local

Comment: Why are you running Selenium at all, given that it doesn't actually click the agree button on the client side?

Comment: Do we have compatible version of chrome driver, chrome browser ? what selenium version you are using btw  ?

Comment: It's hard to imagine your use case. Selenium it a testing tool; one would not ordinarily run it in production. Could you explain what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headless software (e.g. "headless Java" or "headless Linux",) is software capable of working on a device without a graphical user interface. ... The term "headless" is most often used when the ordinary version of the program requires that a graphics card or similar graphical interface device be present.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_software

If by "production" you mean a remote server like a VPS or something, Then probably no you can not run a graphical web browser on the server it would have to be headless.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**
Check if the issue persists for all links, give a simple link like google.com
sometimes the issue may persist for sites with

- Bad certificates can be resolved with `--ignore-certificate-errors`
- Self signed certificate can be resolved with `--enable-features=NetworkService`

Alternatively you can opt to not go for headless browser in production and utilise **browserstack** or **saucelabs**. Cloud based continuously testing platform, most ideal for cross browser and cross platform testing

Answer (score -1):

you can selenium headless mode in any kind of environment, it is one of the configurable feature in automation.